# Write formatted JSON to file using Python

Tags: python, shell

I would like to write a formatted (i.e. indented) JSON configuration file to a remote computer using a shell script.

My code:

```
json_config = {
    "api-listen": true, 
    "api-network": true, 
    "multi-version": "1", 
    "pools": [
        {
            "pass": "123", 
            "url": "antpool.com:3333"
        }, 
        {
            "pass": "123", 
            "url": "antpool.com:443"
        }, 
        {
            "pass": "123", 
            "antpool.com:25"
        }
    ]
}

# format the new configuration
json_config_formatted = json.dumps(json.dumps(json_config), indent=4)

# write the new config
connection.sendShell('echo "{}" | cat > "/config/bmminer.conf"'.format(json_config_formatted))
```

However, everything gets written on a single line. How can I preserve the formatting of the string?

Comment: What is `connection` an instance of? Is there a way for it to set standard input for `cat` directly?

Comment: If you were using `subprocess.Popen`, for example, you might use something like `p = Popen(["ssh", remote_host, "cat > /config/bmminer.conf"], stdin=PIPE)` followed by `json.dump(json_config, p.stdin)`. `cat` inherits its standard input from `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are calling json.dumps twice, so you are making a single JSON string which itself contains JSON.

Second, you should write the file with Python, not a shell.

```
json_config = {
    ...
}

# format the new configuration
with open("/config/bmminer.conf", "w") as conf:
    json.dump(json_config, conf, indent=4)
```

For a remote computer, how you get the data there correctly depends on your library.  I don't know what `sendShell` is.

Comment: sendShell sends the data to a remote machine that I am connected to with SSH. So, I can actually write to the file with Python.

Comment: If you told us where you got sendShell from, we could read the docs and help you find a way to use it the way you need.